# Making custom WP theme, permalinks go to top of frontpage

Tags: php, wordpress

I've made multipage websites before but this is my first attempt at a WP theme and I'm not too familiar with how WP behaves. Can someone explain to me how Wordpress knows what file to use as a template for the permalink target?

I have a custom made frontpage (index.php) with a loop that generates "teasers" to my blog posts with the post titles containing the permalinks generated through the_permalink(). But when I click on the link, it just takes me up to the top of the page. I'm assuming WP is using my index.php as a template for the permalink, but I want to use a different .php template, since index.php is my frontpage. How do I tell WP to go to use different page template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress, a page is typically built up from a number of different template files. The specific files used depend on the type of content being displayed and the options chosen, rather than the permalink.

Typically index.php is your base template. It may be a wrapper which performs a loop, and pulls in a sub-template for each post. Small content templates describe how to show specific things, like a post. So index.php would have the wrapper html and the loop, while content.php would have the template for each post.

You then have a set of other page templates depending on the content type such as
`single.php` - a single post
`page.php` - a single page
`page-i-made.php` - a custom page template, which you can choose when you create the page.
etc.

There is a list of these content templates in the [Theme Development page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) of the Wordpress codex.

So in your case to set up single post pages, you would be looking at single.php and perhaps content.php.

Comment: Ahh okay I see, so the type of content dictates the template. Gotta read into WP posts and pages. then. I also renamed the template I wanted to display single posts to single.php and it worked. Thanks!